# Cannot read a string from json processor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quarkus

I made searchs and I applied the answers I found by adding dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is code :

```
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/room-available-by-type")
    public Response getAvailableRoomsByType(String request_) throws DataException, IOException {
        Reader reader = new StringReader(request_);
        JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(reader);
        JsonObject request = jsonReader.readObject();
        jsonReader.close();
        reader.close();
        String arrival = request.getString("dateArrivee");
        String departure = request.getString("dateDepart");
        JsonArray rooms = request.getJsonArray("roomList");
        System.out.println("================== arrival dans getAvailableRoomsByType = "+arrival);
        final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        List<Xxx> roomList = new ArrayList<>();
        Xxx xxx = new Xxx();
        xxx.setTypeChambre("xxx");
        roomList.add(xxx);
        return Response.ok(roomList, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
```

But at runtime I get exception `Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found`
I also tried this dependencies :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

but the error still persists. I made `mvn clean install -DskipTests` after modifying the pom.xml. So what is wrong ?

**update :**

here is pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.fnptechnologies</groupId>
  <artifactId>mat</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.3.3</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.1.2</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-mailer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-mailer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.28</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-jsonb</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.1</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.14.Final</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20231013</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Is it a Spring or Quarkus project?
What version of the framework are you using?

Comment: @BorislavGizdov I edited the post to include the pom.xml of the project

Comment: Your resource should work, you have to not use javax dependencies in quarkus 3.x. Check my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample app and it is working. You can find it at: https://github.com/bgizdov/quarkus-3-resteasy-jsonb-sample.

It seems that there is an issue with your dependencies. In Quarkus 3.x, you need to use jakarta.* packages instead of javax.* packages. In my project, I use JSONB for JSON serialization/deserialization, just like in your code.

Your resource actually works. I have created an improved version that:

- Receives the request body as an object, rather than as a string.
- Returns the response as an object and leaves Quarkus and JSON.

```
@POST
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Path("/room-available-by-type-2")
  public AvailabilityResponse getAvailableRoomsByType2(AvailableRoomsRequest request) {
    String arrival = request.getDateArrive();
    String departure = request.getDateDepart();
    List<String> rooms = request.getRoomList();
    System.out.println("================== arrival dans getAvailableRoomsByType = " + arrival);
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    List<AvailabilityResponse> roomList = new ArrayList<>();

    AvailabilityResponse availabilityResponse = new AvailabilityResponse();
    availabilityResponse.setTypeChambre("xxx");
    roomList.add(availabilityResponse);
    return availabilityResponse;
  }
```

Tests

```
package org.acme;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import jakarta.json.bind.Jsonb;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@QuarkusTest
class RoomsResourceTest {
  @Test
  void getAvailableRoomsByType() {
    given()
        .body(
            "{\"dateArrivee\":\"2021-01-01\",\"dateDepart\":\"2021-01-02\",\"roomList\":[{\"typeChambre\":\"xxx\"}]}")
        .when()
        .post("/rooms/room-available-by-type")
        .then()
        .statusCode(200);
  }

  @Test
  void getAvailableRoomsByType2() {
    final String body = getBody();
    given()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(body)
        .when()
        .post("/rooms/room-available-by-type-2")
        .then()
        .log()
        .all()
        .statusCode(200)
        .body("typeChambre", org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo("xxx"));
  }

  private static String getBody() {
    Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();

    AvailableRoomsRequest request = new AvailableRoomsRequest();
    request.setDateArrive("2021-01-01");
    request.setDateDepart("2021-01-02");
    request.setRoomList(new ArrayList<>());
    request.getRoomList().add("xxx");
    String body = jsonb.toJson(request); // Rest assured still not support jakarta.json.bind
    return body;
  }
}
```

Tests:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.acme.RoomsResourceTest
2023-12-22 18:24:21,507 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.6.4) started in 1.460s. Listening on: http://localhost:8081
2023-12-22 18:24:21,508 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated.
2023-12-22 18:24:21,508 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy-reactive, resteasy-reactive-jsonb, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
================== arrival dans getAvailableRoomsByType = 2021-01-01
================== arrival dans getAvailableRoomsByType = 2021-01-01
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 21
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
    "typeChambre": "xxx"
}
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.915 s -- in org.acme.RoomsResourceTest
2023-12-22 18:24:22,693 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) code-with-quarkus stopped in 0.036s
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.246 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-22T18:24:22+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Note**: it seems that there are still issues with using jsonb in restassured for testing. Additionally, it appears that restassured still relies on javax, and you are unable to pass an object as the body in restassured. Otherwise, you will encounter an error in the tests, specifically "NoClassDefFound javax/json/bind/Jsonb".
I prefer to use Jackson usually.

Comment: ok, thank you for your effort, but it seems heavy, I just switched using `org.json.JSONObject`, so I just wrote `JSONObject request = new JSONObject(request_);`

Comment: That is working, anyway I avoid manually parsing JSONs from strings. I prefer automatic deserialization to a Java object with Jackson. It is easier, faster to code, and less risky in terms of making errors.